# Twitter Omniauth Profile Picture Broken after changed on Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I have twitter ommiauth as my user model and I pull in when they register a link of their profile picture via the hash auth.info.image. Iv noticed some are now breaking where the user has updated their profile picture on Twitter.

I noticed there is a part of the hash that gets the image over https (profile_image_url_https) in the raw_info section. Details here https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter. is this the best practice to link to so it doesnt happen again?

My issue is that I may have a user that logs in once and leaves a comment but then their profile changes and it breaks on the site.

Is there another way I should be implementing this?

Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a fix for this? I'm facing the same problem too. :(

Comment: No fix as of yet. I did change the profile picture I pull. I now take over https. Just need to wait for someone to change their profile picture now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving the twitter image url when a user creates an account or logs in via oAuth and not checking whether it has changed when attempting to display it this would be expected. The only thing I can think of to fix disappearing links would be to test the data with an http or url call and replace it with a placeholder image or ping the API to retrieve the updated image.